# Fetching only the Mobile Number from Android contacts

Tags: java, android

how would I modify the following code so that it grabs the  name(which it already does) and the mobile number from Android contacts? I would like the phone number labeled as mobile in contacts.

```
private ArrayList<ContactInfo> getLegalContacts() {

        ArrayList<ContactInfo> legalContacts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> contacts = loadLegalContacts();

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            if (phoneNumber != null) {
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(")", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+", "");
            }
            if (contacts.contains(id)) {
                ContactInfo info = new ContactInfo(id, name, phoneNumber, true);
                boolean isNew = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < legalContacts.size(); i++) {
                    if (TextUtils.equals(legalContacts.get(i).name, name)) {
                        isNew = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (isNew) {
                    legalContacts.add(info);
                }
            }
        }
        phones.close();

        return legalContacts;
    }

    private List<String> loadLegalContacts() {
        List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> set = SharedPrefUtil.getInstance().getStringSet("LegalContacts");
        if (set != null) {
            contacts.addAll(set);
        }

        return contacts;
    }
```

Comment: At present it seems to only grab the first number it is presented with. does it means if the number is say 1234567890 it is giving only 1 ?

Comment: No, I mean that it grabs the first full phone number from the contacts of each person.

Comment: So what is the problem then you want both name and phone number right ? you are getting both of them now ... Or am I missing anything here ?

Comment: I would like the mobile number. The one that is labeled as the mobile number in contacts.

Comment: Thanks! Everything is up and running!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
private ArrayList<ContactInfo> getLegalContacts() {

        ArrayList<ContactInfo> legalContacts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> contacts = loadLegalContacts();

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            String labelString = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            if(labelString!=null)
            {
                int type = Integer.parseInt(labelString);
                if(type==ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    Log.d("LableTag", " lable is : " + type);
                    if (phoneNumber != null) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(", "");
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(")", "");
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("-", "");
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(" ", "");
                        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+", "");
                    }
                    if (contacts.contains(id)) {
                        ContactInfo info = new ContactInfo(id, name, phoneNumber, true);
                        boolean isNew = true;
                        for (int i = 0; i < legalContacts.size(); i++) {
                            if (TextUtils.equals(legalContacts.get(i).getName(), name)) {
                                isNew = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (isNew) {
                            legalContacts.add(info);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        phones.close();

        return legalContacts;
    }
```

`labelString` will hold the value of currently it is labeled as

Then we need to check whether it is a mobile type if true then we access it and add it to list

For more info visit [ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone)

Comment: Thank you, AgentP. I added the code to my HomeActivity.java. However, it gave my 37 errors. Most are Illegal start expression and ";" expected Errors. What should do from this point?

Comment: You might be adding a ; somewhere which is not needed you need to remove it

Comment: Thanks. I will check that. Also, I was wondering did you mean "Label" in the code above when you said "Log.d("LableTag", " lable is : " + type);"

Comment: No I have kept a labelString variable that's one it will be holding the type of number i.e Phone, Mobile etc